# How do I know where the bluetooth data is coming from via hcidump?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Mitutoyo bluetooth tool which would send the data from the measurement instrument.

In general, it would behavior like a bluetooth keyboard ,which would key-in a number to my computer.

I would expect that I will get numerous these kinds of instruments , and each instrument would key-in its own number to the computer. With more than two of them I would no way to know where each of the number is coming from.

I'm using

> hcidump -R -x

to see the raw data, I hope that I can distinguish which data is coming from which instrument
the data looks like :

```
02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 27 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 37 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 1F 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 00 00 

02 40 20 0F 00 0B 00 04 00 1B 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

which means 0.214 (refer to  27 37 1F 1E 21)

However, I don't know how to know where the data comes from by this data. My tool's address is 58:93:D8:C6:6B:47 and it's name is 0710005203 but I cannot match these info to the package data I received from the hcidump.

Could I use hcidump to just monitor a specific device's data?

(I find a command call hcidump -i but it seems to specific the bluetool device on the computer, not my slave tool)